# Matlab error while calculating double integral

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate a double integral but get an error.

My code is:

```
clear 
Gamma  = rand([22,1]);
data_i = rand([1,10]);
Y_1    = 1;
fun     = @(D_star, Y_0 ) fun1(D_star , Y_1 , Y_0 , Gamma , data_i);
p       = integral2  ( fun ,  0 , 1 , 0 , 1);
```

and the function fun1 is defined as

```
function [p] = fun1(D_star , Y_1 , Y_0 , Gamma , data_i)

gamma=Gamma(1:3);
beta_1=Gamma(4:5);
beta_0=Gamma(6:7);
alpha_D=Gamma(8);
alpha_1=Gamma(9);
alpha_0=Gamma(10);
sigma2_1=Gamma(11);
sigma2_0=Gamma(12);
Lambda=Gamma(13:17);
sigma2_M=Gamma(18:22);

Sigma2_temp = [1 ; sigma2_1 ; sigma2_0 ; sigma2_M];
Alpha       = [alpha_D ; alpha_1 ; alpha_0 ; Lambda];
Sigma2      = Alpha * Alpha' + diag(Sigma2_temp);

Z = data_i(3:5);
X = data_i(3:4);
M = data_i(6:10);

Mu = [Z*gamma , X*beta_1 , X*beta_0 , zeros(1,5) ]';

YY = [D_star ; Y_1 ; Y_0 ; M' ];

p  =  mvnpdf(YY,Mu,Sigma2);
end
```

I don't think there is a problem in the definition of the functions because I can evaluate them (e.g. fun(1,1) give me an answer). The error message that I get is:

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in fun1 (line 23)
YY = [D_star ; Y_1 ; Y_0 ; M' ];

Error in @(D_star,Y_0)fun1(D_star,Y_1,Y_0,Gamma,data(n,:))


Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 228)
        Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 106)
    Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

I tried also the command -quad2d- instead of -integral2- and got a similar error. Any ideas?

Comment: The error message says it all. You're trying to concatente matrices whose sizes don't match.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why because the function by itself works, so it must to be something with the integration.

Comment: Obviously. That line concatenates 4 elements, three are directly taken from input parameters. So your input parameters are the wrong shapes or sizes.

Comment: Put a debug break at the start of the function, and step through the computation. See where things go wrong. It's a lot easier and faster than to ask on SO... :p

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. According to the documentation, when using  -integral2-, the function inside the integral must get an array of both variables as an input and return an array as an output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. According to the documentation, when using -integral2-, the function inside the integral must get an array of both variables as an input and return an array as an output.